# DNS host name not resolving without http:// prefix

Tags: networking, dns, raspberry-pi, dnsmasq

I am using DnsMasq on raspberry pi. On the `/etc/dnsmasq.conf` configuration is as follows:

```
 interface=eth0
 domain-needed
 bogus-priv
 strict-order
 addn-hosts=/etc/hosts.dnsmasq
```

And the `/etc/hosts.dnsmasq` is:

```
192.168.0.2 abcd.bus
192.168.0.2 www.abcd.bus
```

I configured static IP to Raspberry Pi and running Apache web server. 
when I hit the "http://abcd.bus" and "http://www.abcd.bus" on the browser it resolves and shows the webpage . But the problem is when I hit only "abcd.bus" or "www.abcd.bus" without http:// it is not resolving and shows webpage not found.

Why browser is not prefix "http://" on resolving? Is there any configuration to do that?

I am Using Google Chrome browser.

Comment: We have no idea what the problem is in your browser if you don't tell us what your browser is.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq why you down vote for this? If you have any ans then write it

Comment: It is impossible to answer because you haven't told us what your browser is.

Comment: @qasdfdsaq edited check

Comment: Chrome uses a search box not an address bar. When you type something without an http:// you are telling Chrome to search for "abcd.bus" on Google.com

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to flush your dns table after making an edit in your hosts file.  In windows it's ipconfig /flushdns in the command prompt.  not sure about linux.